# Linked list with flexible array

Tags: arrays, c, list

I have a homework of factory automation application to be done with linked lists. Since number of departments and amount of transferable departments from one can change, I decided to use flexible array for struct node *next. For entrance department (i = 0) the program works kinda perfect, but beyond a point it goes crazy.

The struct node I defined

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node *next[];
};
```

Since we use an input file for necessary variables, these are also defined (my language is Turkish):

```
struct birKay{
int birimNo;
float islemZaman;
int birimIliski;
};

struct urKay{
    float gelisZaman;
};

struct birKay birimKayit={0,0.0,0};
struct urKay urunKayit={0.0};
```

Here is the "simulasyon" (simulation) function that is supposed to build structures, which it still fails (the code is as it is at the time of writing):

```
system("cls");
int i,j,k,l,birSay,ilis,birIdeal,saySifir;
input = fopen("input.txt","r");
printf("Simulasyon baslatiliyor...\n");
printf("Girdi dosyasi okunuyor...\n");
fscanf(input,"%d",&birSay);
float workTime[birSay];
bool ilisMatris[birSay][birSay];
int ilSayDiz[birSay];
printf("Iliski matrisi cikariliyor...\n");
for(i = 0; i < birSay; i++)
{
    ilSayDiz[i] = 0;
    printf("%d",ilSayDiz[i]);
    for(j = 0; j < birSay; j++)
        ilisMatris[i][j] = false;
    fscanf(input,"%d %f %d",&birimKayit.birimNo,&workTime[i],&birimKayit.birimIliski);
    for(j = 0; j < birimKayit.birimIliski; j++)
    {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&ilis);
        ilisMatris[i][ilis] = true;
        ilSayDiz[i]++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",ilSayDiz[i]); 
}
fclose(input);
printf("Fabrika yapisi tanimlaniyor...\n");
struct node *start = NULL;
struct node *new_node, *ptr;
start=yapi_yukle(start,0);
for(i = 0; i < birSay; i++) //sorunlu kısım
{
    k = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < birSay; j++)
    {
        if(ilisMatris[i][j] == 1)
        {
            new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            new_node -> data = j;
            ptr = start;
            if(i == 0)
            {
                ptr -> next[k] = new_node;
                new_node -> next[k] = NULL;
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                for(l = 0; l <= ilSayDiz[i]; l++)
                {
                    if(l == ilSayDiz[i])
                        if(ptr -> next[k] != NULL)
                            ptr = ptr -> next[k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("\nSimulasyon sonlandirildi... ");
printf("Ana menuye donmek icin bir tusa basin...");
getch();
system("cls");
main();
```

The "yapi_yukle" function:

```
struct node *yapi_yukle(struct node *start,int num)
{
    struct node *new_node, ptr;
    new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node -> data = num;
    new_node -> next[0] = start;
    start = new_node;
    return start;
}
```

I have three other functions (main, inputFileCreator and fabrikaOku (reading parametres taken from input file)), all work perfect.

I don't really know what to do. I try something and program goes crazy (probably from infinite loops or something, but I can't detect them).

I use Dev-C++ 5.11 to write C code and any attempt of debugging ANY code results in a crash.

Any kind of suggestions are welcomed.

EDIT: For whose are curious, here's the format of input file (with an example, taken from homework document):
5 //number of departments

0 2.2364 2 1 2 //department number, worktime, number of departments it can transfer its products to, departments it can transfer its products to

1 4.5683 1 3

2 5.9876 2 3 4

3 3.8976 0

4 2.6789 0

20 //number of items this factory processes
0.3504 //the amount of time the item comes to factory

0.9768

1.3085

5.0263

5.1213

5.9992

6.4886

10.4749

11.8744

13.4648

14.2401

14.2904

14.6714

20.7265

26.4457

32.0276

35.0026

36.2470

38.0850

42.1120

Comment: How will you know how big the FAM is in the structure?  Why would a node need an array of next nodes?

Comment: I thought that would be a good idea since it all depends on an input file that gives number of departures, their worktime, number of departures they can transfer their product to and departures they can transfer their product to. Number of departures aspect is what made me think of flexible array in a struct node *next, since it can change anyways and anytime.